# Youtube API: How do request only safe advertisements?

Tags: api, youtube, gdata

I am trying to use YouTube API on a project. Is there a way to ask YouTube to display only safe advertisements? I don't want kids watching horror movie trailers when they watch YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube lets you block certain ads on a site basis http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164131 but I don't see horroR film trailers in that list.  If you don't want offensive ads you should use a paid service like Vimeo and get no ads at all.